# Push to two remote repos with different users

Tags: git, github

I have a github user account called `user1` and I want to push some code to another repo `repo2` from `user2` which I've got the privilege on and added as collaborator. 
Currently I'm getting `Permission denied` when trying to push. What's the step to do it?

Comment: What is the output from `git remote -v`? Do you have the credentials for `user2`?

Comment: `origin  git@github.com:user2/repo2.git (fetch)`
`origin  git@github.com:user2/repo2.git (push)`

Comment: How are you authenticating each user? Do you use HTTPS or SSH?

Comment: I used ssh. I tried https and it worked. thanks

Comment: I have not yet figured out how to set up SSH with GitHub for two different users from the same machine. If you figure it out, you should post an answer here.

Comment: At the end, I push to both repo by one user. I gave permission to `user1` on both `repo1` and `repo2`. And used https to push my changes for both repos. I tried it with ssh and it didn't work.

Comment: If you uploaded a SSH key for user1, then it will work for all repos.